# Rotate horizontal image to fit vertical space in grid

Tags: css, image, rotation, grid, responsive

I have a grid with items from a (wordpress) gallery. In making a responsive layout I would like to be able adjust the grid and rotate the image if I have a vertical space (row spans) to cover this space. when I rotate the img now, it gets clipped to the original size. The grid area seems to rotate along.

How to rotate without clipping? See black vertical space in image, brown colors are other images.
with different spans, in blue the rotated grid area.

HTML

```
<div class="entry-content"> 
<figure class="wp-block-gallery has-nested-images columns-default is-cropped wp-block-gallery-7 is-layout-flex"> 
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="625" height="208" data-id="69"  src="http://localhost/bouwqunst/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/huislab.png" alt="" class="wp-image-69" srcset="http://localhost/iets/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/iets.png 625w, http://localhost/iets/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/iets-300x100.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 625px) 100vw, 625px" /></figure>
...
```

CSS

```
figure.wp-block-gallery.has-nested-images {
display: grid;
grid-auto-rows: 10vw;
grid-template-columns: 10vw 20vw 38vw 20vw 10vw ;
column-gap: .5vw;
row-gap: .5vw;}

figure.wp-block-gallery.has-nested-images  .wp-block-image {
width: auto !important;
-webkit-filter: sepia(100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
filter: sepia(100%);
transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;}

#section-vertical figure.wp-block-gallery.has-nested-images  .wp-block-image:nth-child(1){transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%) translateY(-30%);transform-origin: top left; }
```

[image: Image with grid area rotated in blue.]

Comment: We need more code (HTML, CSS) for us to be able to assist you.

Comment: I addded some html and css. I have no idea what other code is related to this issue.